# mysql sleep wont work if the first resutl is false

Tags: mysql, sql

```
mysql> select * from users where id=0;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from users where id=0 and sleep(5);
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from users where id=0 and benchmark(1000000,sha1(1));
Empty set (0.39 sec)

mysql> select * from users where id=0 xor sleep(5);
Empty set (1 min 5.02 sec)
```

when id=0, the user doesn't exist. why the second query doesn't sleep 5s? when I use `benchmark（1000000,sha1(1))` or `xor sleep(5)`, why it will sleep?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is called "short-circuiting" and it is considered a feature of pretty much all databases -- and almost all programming languages.

Logic that does not need to be executed is not executed.  It has nothing to do with `sleep()`.  It is simply desirable to stop executing code when the engine already knows the answer.

I do not think that forcing a `sleep()` within a single query is a good idea.  SQL Queries are *not* intended to be procedural.  They describe the result set and the query engine generates the appropriate code.  `sleep()` is not in the scope of SQL result sets.

I would recommend that -- if a `sleep()` really is necessary -- that you do it with a separate step in your scripts.

Comment: Thanks, I'm testing the SQL injection, the results of sleep time confuse me.  `select * from users where id=0 and (select*from(select sleep(5))x)` , why this query can sleep 5s? the engine should already knows the answer.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  Using `(SELECT * FROM (SELECT ...` forces the inner query, sleep(5), to be evaluated first, and its result materialized into an implicit temporary table called "x" before `WHERE id = 0` is discovered to match nothing.